# 404 Error when trying to access Web API 2 Service deployed to IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, iis-7.5, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a standalone `REST` service using `Web API 2` framework. The project contains no UI as the service will be consumed elsewhere on another domain.

The service works completely fine when running locally and all HTTP methods work/return as expected when testing with an in-browser REST client.

However, after publishing the service and deploying to `IIS 7.5`, I cannot access any of the resources for any of the routes for my service in the REST client. I am continually being returned a `404 - Resource Not Found` error.

**Things I have already done:**

Added the following to my `Web.Config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Ensured AppPool is correct (as far as I am aware this is correct):
[image]

**It may also be useful to know my publishing configuration for my publishing profile:**

- Publishing method: File system
- Configuration: Debug
- Delete all existing files prior to publish: No
- Precompile during publishing: No
- Exclude files from App_Data folder: Yes

**IIS Bindings:**

- Type: HTTP
- Hostname: www.MySubdomain.Domain.co.uk
- Port: 80
- IP Address: *

**An example URL of how I am trying to access my service in the REST client is as follows:**

- `www.MySubDomain.Domain.co.uk/api/ControllerName/1` (GET)
- (This works fine locally using `api/ControllerName/1`)

Any additional things to try would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the Web Site bindings defined in IIS administrator, and the url you're using to try to connect to the service. You can try the old trick of including a .html file in the root and try to acces it, but there is no warranty that your sever serves it by default.

Comment: @JotaBe - I have edited my question to include this info. Thanks.

Comment: I have a localized IIS manager, but try to find "controller (handlers?) assignments" or something like that, under the IIS section. Check if "Static file" is there, and enabled. If so, try putting a file in the root of the server, and accessing it through the url. Or try to set a default document, create a "home.html" and access the site root.

Comment: check to ensure CORS is enabled.

Comment: Turns out my bindings were slightly incorrect! As I am hosting it on a sub-domain I did not require the `www.` in my bindings. Works fine once I removed these 4 characters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my bindings were slightly incorrect! As I am hosting it on a sub-domain I did not require the `www.` in my bindings. Works fine once I removed these 4 characters!